# How to change response format of Django auth login api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am currently using [Django-rest-framework-social-oauth2](https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2) and it's login token creation endpoint, which on success, responds with the following data:

```
{
  "access_token": "************",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 36000,
  "refresh_token": "************",
  "scope": "read write"
}
```

But I want to change the format and wrap the data in that format:

```
{
  "status" : true,
  "data" :{
      "access_token": "************",
      "token_type": "Bearer",
      "expires_in": 36000,
      "refresh_token": "************",
      "scope": "read write"
    }
}
```

I read the Django documentation and tried extending the library view but no changes are showing up

```
from rest_framework_social_oauth2.views import TokenView 

    @api_view(('POST'))
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Use the rest framework `.data` to fake the post body of the django request.
        request._request.POST = request._request.POST.copy()
        for key, value in request.data.items():
            request._request.POST[key] = value

        url, headers, body, status = self.create_token_response(request._request)
        response = Response(data=json.loads(body), status=status)

        for k, v in headers.items():
            response[k] = v
        return response
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to create a [class based view](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views) and extend DRF-social-oauth2's [`TokenView`](https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2/blob/master/rest_framework_social_oauth2/views.py#L21) which has a method `post` to create the token:

1. `views.py`:

   ```
   from rest_framework_social_oauth2.views import TokenView

   class MyTokenView(TokenView):

       def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           response = super(MyTokenView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
           return Response({
               'status': Your_Status,
               'data': response.data,
           }, status=response.status_code)
   ```

   The `.super` method will create the desired token and then you can manipulate the response given as shown (and with a plethora of other ways if you need!).
2. You also need to add a url endpoint in your `urls.py` for authentication:

   ```
   from my_project/my_app import MyTokenView

   urlpatterns = [
       ...
       url(
           r'^my_api/authenticate/$', 
           MyTokenView.as_view(), 
           name='authenticate'),
       ...
   ]
   ```

---

*Keep in mind:* Since you are extending the `TokenView` class you should handle the **Failure responses** as well.

Comment: Hi there, had to change name param value to  `authorize` and it worked perfectly. Thanks much!

Comment: @user8169843 Happy to help mate :). 
You can accept the answer if you want, by clicking on the tic icon!

Comment: You deserve it. Thanks again!

Comment: is there any way to return user_id in response as well, I think I need  create a custom backend for it?

Comment: @user8169843 If you see the `post()` above, it has an argument called `request`. Use this as `request.user.id` or `request.user.pk`.

Comment: and output of request.user.id  is null

Comment: request.user.is_authenticated also returns false

Comment: All that mean that your user doesn't get correctly authenticated. You didn't provide the correct token or the correct credentials.

Comment: No, user credentials are right. I do get the access and refresh tokens after sending a request, but request.user.is_authenticated returns false

Comment: I used, `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)` before getting a response from `TokenView` and now I can retrieve user details from `user`. I am not sure if I am doing it right way, as TokenView itself must return user after authentication?

Comment: I believe that you are doing it correctly @user8169843 .